# Export MSSQL DB, Import in shared environment

Tags: sql-server, import, export, schema

We are in the process of trying to migrate from a VPS to a shared environment. The VPS is running Studio Express 2005 so is therefore limited quite a lot in functionality in terms of exporting.

I have managed to export a database in .bak format and upload (Restore) it to the shared environment.

However, here comes the problem, the schema has come with the database. Causing problems when connecting via asp.

The table name structure is as follows [SCHEMA].[TABLE_NAME].
The shared environment does not allow for changing of schema or many advanced features. (Its running myLittleAdmin).
So I guess the schema changes would have to be done on the database, then exported then imported.

Ps. I'm new to MSSQL and more experienced in MYSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I have found a solution to this.

- Export the schema from Studio Express using Right Click > Tools > Generate Script.
- Execute this script on the server.
- Open this file, find and replace the old user with your new one.
- Use a tool such as this one http://sqldumper.ruizata.com/ (SQL Dumper) to export the DB to .SQL.
- Find and replace on this file, again for the old user to the new.
- Copy this SQL and execute it on the server.

Job done!

Joe